# Prove that q(x) is irreducible over F(u) if p(x) and q(x) are irreducible in F[x] and their degrees are relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory

"Let p(x) and q(x) be irreducible in F[x] and assume that deg p(x) is relatively prime to deg q(x). Let u be a root of p(x) and v a root of q(x) in some extension field of F. Prove that q(x) is irreducible over F(u)."

I will use the results of a previous problem:
Let $F$ be a subfield of $K$.
Assume that $u,v\in K$ are algebraic over $F$, with minimal polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.
If $\operatorname{deg}p(x)=m$ and $\operatorname{deg}q(x)=n$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n) = 1$, prove that $[F(u,v):F] = mn$.

First we can multiply p(x) and q(x) by a constant so their leading coefficient is 1 so they become the minimal polynomial of u and v respectively.
Now we have the following:
$[F(u):F][F(u,v):F(u)]=[F(u,v):F] = mn$ and $[F(v):F][F(u,v):F(v)]=[F(u,v):F] = mn$ From the problem above we can see that the minimal polynomial of [F(u,v):F(v)] and [F(u,v):F(u)] are still the same (p(x) and q(x) multiplied by a constant) so we can conclude that q(x) is irreducible over F(u) and p(x) is irreducible over F(v).

Is the logic correct?

Comment: Please add the [solution-verification] tag when you want people to review your work. Also, remember to use MathJax for all math. I for one would subconsciously think that, for instance, F and $F$ represent different things, because the typeface is different.

Comment: “minimal polynomial of $[F(u,v):F(v)]$ and $[F(u,v):F(u)]$” doesn’t mean anything. $[K:L]$ is an integer.

Comment: Can you show that $F(u, v) $ is of degree $n$ over $F(u) $?

Comment: It appears you have the right idea, but you need to present it precisely. In particular you need to fix the issue pointed by @ThomasAndrews.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh hi, the proof that the minimal polynomial of F(u,v) is of degree n over F(u) is proven in another problem. So for this problem, I am assuming that is something we can use.  Given that is the case, can we conclude that the minimal polynomial of F(u,v) is of degree n over F(u) is in fact the same minimal polynomial as  F(v) over F.

Comment: If the degree of $F(u, v) $ over $F(u) $ is $n$ it means that the minimal polynomial $r(x)$ of $v$ over $F(u) $ is of degree $n$ and it divides $q(x) $ which is also of degree $n$. Thus $q(x)$ is a constant multiple of $r(x) $ and hence irreducible over $F(u) $.

Comment: Always try to map the degree of field extensions to the degree of minimal polynomials and use divisibility of polynomials. It's a key technique in field theory and used in amazing ways to derive many results.